# how can i get value from activity recognition to main activity? android development

Tags: java, android, android-activity

This is my code please take a look,should I use bundle or create a object to get value.

```
public class ActivityReconitionServer extends IntentService {


public ActivityReconitionServer() {
    super("ActivityRecognizedService");

}

public ActivityReconitionServer(String name) {
    super(name);
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    if(ActivityRecognitionResult.hasResult(intent)) {
        ActivityRecognitionResult result = ActivityRecognitionResult.extractResult(intent);
        handleDetectedActivities( result.getProbableActivities() );
    }
}
```

please take a look.12315468979

```
private void handleDetectedActivities(List<DetectedActivity> probableActivities) {
    for( DetectedActivity activity : probableActivities ) {
        switch( activity.getType() ) {
            case DetectedActivity.IN_VEHICLE: {
                Log.e( "ActivityRecogition", "In Vehicle: " + activity.getConfidence() );
                break;
            }
            case DetectedActivity.ON_BICYCLE: {
                Log.e( "ActivityRecogition", "On Bicycle: " + activity.getConfidence() );
                break;
            }
            case DetectedActivity.ON_FOOT: {
                Log.e( "ActivityRecogition", "On Foot: " + activity.getConfidence() );
                break;
            }
            case DetectedActivity.RUNNING: {
                Log.e( "ActivityRecogition", "Running: " + activity.getConfidence() );

                break;
            }
            case DetectedActivity.STILL: {
                Log.e( "ActivityRecogition", "Still: " + activity.getConfidence() );
                break;
            }
            case DetectedActivity.TILTING: {
                Log.e( "ActivityRecogition", "Tilting: " + activity.getConfidence() );
                break;
            }
            case DetectedActivity.WALKING: {
                Log.e( "ActivityRecogition", "Walking: " + activity.getConfidence() );
                if( activity.getConfidence() >= 75 ) {
                    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
                    builder.setContentText( "Are you walking?" );
                    builder.setSmallIcon( R.mipmap.ic_launcher );
                    builder.setContentTitle( getString( R.string.app_name ) );
                    NotificationManagerCompat.from(this).notify(0, builder.build());
                }
                break;
            }
            case DetectedActivity.UNKNOWN: {
                Log.e( "ActivityRecogition", "Unknown: " + activity.getConfidence() );
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

should i create a object to get value or use bundle to get value?Please give me some advices